# When an Automatic Rewrite is triggered from Billing center, when and where does the term number gets updated for the rewrite transaction in code level

Tags: url-rewriting, guidewire

When an Automatic Rewrite is triggered from Billing center, when and where does the term number gets updated for the rewrite transaction in code level

When I checked in PC code, I did not find any explicit code where we are incrementing the term number

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to see this code in Gosu classes or enhancements since the logic to increment TermNumber on Renewal or Rewrite is obfuscated in Guiderwire's internal methods and jars. My best guess would be that it happens in the function `generated/entity/PolicyPeriod#updateTermNumber()`. The documentation and description of the `TermNumber` column suggest that the initial value for this column is 1 and keeps getting incremented by 1 at a renewal or rewrite.

While you can override or customize this behavior by blocking this method call and replacing it with your own implementation, attempting to do so will give rise to a plethora of issues. In case you want to customize or configure the way `TermNumber` behaves, the safest way would be to create another column `TermNumber_Ext` which is managed by you and can easily map to the out of the box `TermNumber`. For example, if the carrier requires the term number to start from `001` instead of 1, you can make the Ext field a `String` and be responsible for setting it's value at all the right places in `JobProcess` and its subclasses. This approach may not be as easy as it sounds, but avoids conflicts with platform level code and keeps your customer logic isolated.

Comment: As Abhijay mentions, this happens in internal code and is documented and unchangeable behavior of term numbering inside PolicyCenter.  Do not attempt to override or change this behavior.  As suggested, if necessary create a custom field to fulfill your requirements, or shift your requirements to align with the ootb behavior of TermNumber in PC and BC.

Comment: Thank you Abhijay and Martin. But in my case, During Rewrite new term, If the term number should be 3, It is populating wrongly as 2. And in JobProcess class, For another  certain conditions, we are explicitly incrementing the term number(_branch.termNumber) by 1. Is it the right way or this code is causing the wrong population of the term number

Comment: That could be a part of the problem. In OTB code, this increment happens internally and not explicitly in the job process classes. Try to compare your code with OTB by right-clicking the file and selecting "Compare with Base File". The internal method call may have been suppressed in your case. Ensure that the job process classes are as close to the base implementation as possible.

Comment: When you say "populated wrongly as 2" can you provide more context?  Is it wrong in PC?  Or BC?  Or somewhere else?  And you definitely should NOT be incrementing term number manually.  The product documentation says this about TermNumber:  "The number indicates the term of the policy period, starts with 1 and then increments by 1 for every renewal or rewrite. The built-in PolicyCenter integration with BillingCenter uses the term number instead of the model number to identify a policy."

Comment: @MartinAavik, It is wrongly populated in PC and the term is mismatched between PC and BC

Comment: This appears to be fully custom functionality that has been implemented locally, so it appears that something about how the rewrite is being initiated in PC (or maybe something that happened before the rewrite?) is causing this "mismatch".  I would expect the rewrite to initiate normally in PC with an incremented term number, then when that is issued a rewrite billing instruction would go to BC to establish the new term in BC.  I don't think we're going to give you more help here since there is so much dependency on your local configuration.